# Special or Garbage Characters in curl command Output in Robot Framework

Tags: rest, curl, robotframework

While using a curl command for REST API in Robot framework, I am getting special characters as below in every output line of curl command. How can I remove these Extra characters in output.
e.g. [0m[34;1m  [0m[1;39m   [0m[0;32m etc.

Output from log.html

```
    100 84455    0 84455    0     0   521k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  521k
    * Connection #0 to host left intact
    [1;39m{
    [0m[34;1m"@odata.context"[0m[1;39m: [0m[0;32m"/rest/v0/$metadata#AlarmEntry"[0m[1;39m,
    [0m[34;1m"@odata.id"[0m[1;39m: 
    [0m[0;32m"/rest/v0/AlarmServices/AlarmListService/AlarmEntryCollection"[0m[1;39m,
    [0m[34;1m"@odata.type"[0m[1;39m: [0m[0;32m"#AlarmEntry.0.289.0.AlarmEntry"[0m[1;39m,
    [0m[34;1m"Name"[0m[1;39m: [0m[0;32m"Processor Device Status"[0m[1;39m,
    [0m[34;1m"Id"[0m[1;39m: [0m[0;32m"[0m[1;39m,
    [0m[34;1m"Index"[0m[1;39m: [0m[0;39m54770[0m[1;39m,
    [0m[34;1m"MajorType"[0m[1;39m: [0m[0;39m193[0m[1;39m,
    [0m[34;1m"MinorType"[0m[1;39m: [0m[0;39m11403643[0m[1;39m,
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are ANSI escape codes (for coloring text).
You should not use the progress option `-#` or you can redirect the output to a file `-o` (it probably will not have those escape codes).

Or you can use the options (seen with `curl --help all`):

```
 -S, --show-error         Show error even when -s is used
 -s, --silent             Silent mode
```